# Installing NETCDF4 in windows using python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, netcdf4

I have downloaded NETCDF4 module from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netCDF4
e.g. `netCDF4-1.3.1-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl`

I have installed it using 
pip install `netCDF4-1.3.1-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl`

through command prompt in spyder. It has successfully installed. But when I am trying to import, it is giving an error:

> import netCDF4 as nc4
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import netCDF4 as nc4
>
> File "C:\python3\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.5Qt5\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\netCDF4__init__.py", line 3, in 
>       from ._netCDF4 import *
>
> File "netCDF4_netCDF4.pyx", line 2988, in init netCDF4._netCDF4
>
> AttributeError: type object 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dimension' has no attribute '**reduce_cython**'

How can I fix it? Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. However, it's better to avoid problems, use python 3.6. It has no errors with netCDF4 and it comes with netCDF4.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I am using python 3.7.8 with Anaconda to manage my packages and the primary channel is conda-forge.

I ha to update the cython package:

The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
cython-0.29.21             |   py37h8e8dfb5_1         1.9 MB  conda-forge
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:         1.9 MB
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

> cython     0.29.21-py37h1834ac0_0 -->
> 0.29.21-py37h8e8dfb5_1

This update fixed my issue.

Regards